# Reloading of data in JQgrid on button click is not working

Tags: jqgrid

I have successfully loaded data in my grid. I have enabled cell edit and on clicking a cell it will be in edit mode and multiple cells can be edited. The edited data will be stored later on clicking a custom update button. On clicking another custom button a new row will be added to the grid and that also will be saved on clicking the update button previously mentioned.

Now the problem is when I am trying to reset the edited values(ie. the edited cell values and the new row added before saving) using "reload" functionality nothing happens in the grid.It remains as same with the edited values and the empty new row...

My code is here

```
$scope.init = function() {
        var grid = $("#list");
        var lastSel, dataSel, dataLen;
        var colD, colM, colN, userdata;
        jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url:"getData.htm",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",          
            success: function(result){
                colD = result.colData, 
                colM = result.colModel, 
                colN = result.colNames, 
                userdata = colD.userdata; 
                jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'local',
                    data: colD.rootVar,   
                    colModel:colM,

                    sortorder: 'asc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    gridview: true,                
                    altRows: true,                                  
                    cellEdit:true,
                    footerrow: true,                    
                    scrollbar: true,
                    overflow: scroll,   
                    scrollrows: true,

                    loadonce:true,  

                    autowidth: true,
                    shrinkToFit: false, 

                    editurl: 'clientArray',
                    cellsubmit: 'clientArray', 

                    afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol){ 

                    },                  
                    afterSaveCell : function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) { 
                         var updtd = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getCol', name, false, 'sum'); 
                         var objs = [];
                         objs[name] = updtd;
                         jQuery("#list").jqGrid('footerData','set',objs);
                    },                

                    loadComplete: function(data){  
                        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('footerData','set',{'Employer':'Max Guest Count:'});
                        var colnames = jQuery("#list").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel'); 

                        dataLen = colnames.length;  
                        dataSel = colnames[3]['name'];                  

                        for (var i = 3; i < colnames.length; i++){                      
                            var tot = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getCol', colnames[i]['name'], false, 'sum');                            
                            var ob = [];
                            ob[colnames[i]['name']] = tot;
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('footerData','set',ob);
                        }

                        var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
                        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                            grid.setRowData ( ids[i], false, {height: 25} );
                        }

                        jQuery ("table.ui-jqgrid-htable", jQuery("#list")).css ("height", 30);                 
                    },                

                    gridComplete: function () {
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','id',{width:20});
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','Employer',{width:80});
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setColProp','Sponsor',{width:80});

                            var tabs = $("#tabs");
                            var width = tabs.width();
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridWidth', width - 80, true);
                            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridHeight', 270);
                     },         
                });   
            },         
        }); 

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
              useColSpanStyle: true, 
              groupHeaders:[
                {startColumnName: 'id', numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: ''},
                {startColumnName: 'Employer', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: ''},
                {startColumnName: dataSel, numberOfColumns: dataLen, titleText: '<Strong><font color="white">Here Comes</font></Strong>'}
              ] 
        }); 

        $("#addtn").click(function(){
            var newRowData = {"Id":"","Employer":"","Sponsor":"",col1:"",col2:"",col3:"",col4:"",col5:"",col6:"",col7:"",col8:"",col9:"",col10:"",col11:"",col12:"",col13:"",col14:"",col15:"",col16:"",col17:"",col18:"",col19:"",col20:""};
            jQuery("#list").addRowData(0,newRowData,"first",1);             
            jQuery("#list").editRow(0,true);            
        });

        $("#rstbtn").click(function(){
            $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json', page:1, current:true}).trigger('reloadGrid')
       });          
    };  

I will really appreciate if someone can advice on this..
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this line:     `loadonce:true,`  in jqgrid definition. Set it as false and try again.

And for reloading, try this code:

```
 $( '#list' ).trigger( 'reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}] );
```

Comment: Thanks Slacker for your valuable suggestion...I will surely try it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, to load updated data from the array.

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('clearGridData');
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{data: DataArr, datatype:'local'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```